# Transferring Skitch history to new Mac

Tags: macos, data-transfer, skitch

I bought a new MacBook and am wanting to transfer my Skitch history. I've copied all of the `.skitch` files from `~/Pictures/Skitch` on my old MacBook, but Skitch isn't showing them in the history list on my new MacBook Pro.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Skitch employee, Keith, answered this question on [GetSatisfaction](http://getsatisfaction.com/skitch/topics/history21).

The short answer is that you need to copy the following preferences files:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.skitch.skitch.history
~/Library/Preferences/com.skitch.skitch.plist
```

This is in addition to copying the actual `.skitch` files located in:

```
~/Pictures/Skitch
```